# I have trouble installing mtTkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

This window shows up when I attempt to install mtTkinter with "python mtTkinter.py install" through command prompt:

[image]

This is the command prompt log from the install:

[image]

(Highlighter and added/blue pen area is the log)

I am working on a clicker game, like cookie clicker, and Tkinter tends to freeze when using threading. I found mtTkinter, which is multithreading safe.

So I typed in "python mtTkinter.py install" into command prompt. There is no error, it just does not install. The window that opened had the two buttons, [Click Me!] (which gets square brackets added to it over and over) and then QUIT. The Click Me button does nothing, and the quit button closes it.
I am running Windows Vista Python 2.7.11. What am I doing wrong?

Keep in mind I am a beginner at python and computer science, so please be simple with your answers.

Comment: That is the test app that opens when running the `tkinter.py` module as the main, it means that `mtTkinter.py` is not the installation package but the module itself, just import and use it from your program, it doesn't look like it needs to be installed.

Comment: thank you!!! The tutorial I followed (not specifically for mtTkinter) and it said to do it that way. There were now tutorials for mtTkinter alone. Thank you @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 1):

Most tutorials that indicate to run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Will use the specific filename `setup.py`, usually if there is no `setup.py` the file is usable as it is or needs to be installed manually, in this case the `mtTkinter.py` file has no need for installation.

The reason you were seeing the startup window is that that is the test app when you run `tkinter` as the main program (which is what you did) you could see the same popup from the original tkinter by running:

```
python -m Tkinter
```

(The `-m` indicates to run a module)  Obviously tkinter is not an installation package and it actually ignored the `install` argument entirely, it just went to the test app.